# How use jest vue snapshots. Object serialize

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, snapshot

After running the test, a snapshot is created that looks like this

```
<app-expansion-panels-stub items="[object Object]" contentclassnames="" value=""></app-expansion-panels-stub>
```

But I wish it looked like this

```
<app-expansion-panels-stub items="[{ header: title }]" contentclassnames="" value=""></app-expansion-panels-stub>
```

How to properly serialize an object so that it is displayed correctly